# MPMovieplayercontroller on both airplay and idevice

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayer

Is it possible to show the video (synced) on both your iDevice and airplay?

I am using the AVPlayer class now to start a new stream on the apple tv, but I can't get it to sync with the MPMovieplayer I am using to show the video on the iDevice.